# a neural network approach for FIR filter

Tags: signal-analysis, machine-learning, signal-synthesis, neural-network, array-signal-processing

I am trying to write a code for a neural network to do the digital filtering on some signals. Is there any neural network model for digital filtering?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Maybe you can specify a bit more on what is the task? I know of NN which can deal with signal enhancement, beamforming, and other tasks. Each has a very different approach. Without more information, it will be hard to offer any suggentions.

Comment: A simple 1D convolutive layer would do exactly that. On the other hand you might try to read up on sincnets or DDSP.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The FIR filter model you're used to is a series of Neurons with weighted inputs, and a linear activation function.

In other words, a standard FIR filter *is* a neural network.

I mean, it's called "CNN". The C is exactly the operation a filter does.

Comment: I found solution but for the first iteration I need to determined Passband, Stopband and the number of taps. I have no idea that how can I calculate this three parameter!!

Comment: Hi Sam, that's classical *filter design*, there's really a wealth of information and tooling out there. Try PyFDA to design the coefficients of your filter.