# Is it possibel to use CNN to bandpass signal?

Tags: bandpass, machine-learning, time-series

I have a time serie dataset and want to train a CNN-LSTM model to predict as well as detect outliers. How can I use CNN to filter the signal and extract features from specific frequency band?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [a neural network approach for FIR filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/72817/a-neural-network-approach-for-fir-filter)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, actually, I've seen that post before and it does not answer my question, because it does not provide any information about `How` CNN does it. And how to determine which frequency band is included in the filter kernels.

Comment: OK, so you do have the structure and mathematical nature of a CNN in your head. Set that next to the mathematical structure of an FIR filter. Do you see the similarities? A CNN with proportional activation function just implements the exact same math as a FIR filter. Your second question hence is very broad: "how to design an FIR filter", and that's already covered elsewhere, in great depth.

Comment: Ok, basically what you are telling is that CNN is FIR filter, how can I force the CNN layer to act as bandpass in TensorFlow?

Comment: by setting the weights fixed, such that it is the filter you need.